# Bitlocker And Powershell

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I am in need of help regarding powershell command - Enable-Bitlocker

The following code is an example:

```
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString "123456" -AsPlainText -Force

Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -Pin $pw -TpmAndPinProtector -UsedSpaceOnly -SkipHardwareTest -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Start-Sleep 2

(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:HOMEDRIVE).KeyProtector > $env:UserProfile\Desktop\BitLocker_Recovery_Key.txt
```

My problem is , the only output of this command is , the following in the Bitlocker_Recovery_Key.txt

```
KeyProtectorId      : {CC2206C6-1B69-4DC1-96FE-38EED6F576E1}
AutoUnlockProtector : 
KeyProtectorType    : TpmPin
KeyFileName         : 
RecoveryPassword    : 
KeyCertificateType  : 
Thumbprint          :
```

My aim is to acquire the recovery password (48 string password) as a back up for my bitlocker encryption.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `-MountPoint $env:SystemDrive` & `-MountPoint $env:HOMEDRIVE` the same thing? I'm not sure at what point all attributes will be populated with the expected info but the actual encryption of a volume might take longer than 2 seconds.

Comment: Hi , `$env:SystemDrive` is the enviromental variable for where the operating system is installed , this script is globally used therefore we assume the os is not installed on C.

Comment: I think you missed my point - you are enabling BitLocker on `$env:SystemDrive` and moments later you're trying to read KeyProtector from `$env:HOMEDRIVE`.

Comment: Ah , i see it now , Ive ran the encryption again and replaced `$env:HOMEDRIVE` with `$env:SystemDrive` , but the output is the same.
Ive tried running the same command but with xtsaes256 and the results are same
` KeyProtectorId      : {Redacted}
 AutoUnlockProtector :
 KeyProtectorType    : TpmPin
 KeyFileName         :
 RecoveryPassword    :
 KeyCertificateType  :
 Thumbprint          :

Comment: Help would be appriciated...

Still cant retrieve recovery password after using command (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive).KeyProtector > $env:UserProfile\Desktop\BitLocker_Recovery_Key.txt

Comment: Still need an answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem after reading the microsoft documentation of bitlocker
a little bit more thoroughly.

It seems i have done every step required to automate the process , but in order to receive a recovery key , we need to add a recovery password protector (do note that
adding a recovery password protector does not require us to actually submit a password
but only to receive a recovery password and a numerical password)
The process of receiving the password is achieved by invoking the following command
with powershell.

```
Invoke-Expression "Manage-bde -protectors -add <drive of choice or $i if in a loop> -RecoveryPassword"
```

Admin rights are required to activate the protector , the following is the output
By using the command manage-bde -protectors -get <$i or drive letter>

```
Volume : []
All Key Protectors

TPM And PIN:
  ID: 
  PCR Validation Profile:
    

Numerical Password:
  ID: id
  Password:
    password

Numerical Password:
  ID: id
  Password:
    password
```

Only then we can use a recovery key with our method.

Do note , enable-bitlocker or manage-bde -on <drive or $i> does not
automatically produce a recovery password , we need to add the recovery password protector.